# How to make the fields inside any image editable?

Tags: android

I have one image like this coming from server:

[image]

Now I want to convert all the **fields** in the image like "**Date of purchase**", "**Number of units**" **editable**, means user can click on it and can edit the text just like edittext.
I have seen some examples of converting image into pdf but there is hardly any thread which covers my requirement.

I know that by using **ocr** we can read the text on screen but how do i convert it into an editable field even if i manage to read the field.

So please tell me what approach should i follow to solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would ever need to resort to such a measures, but I think you can try this.

You'll need to get the number of EditTexts, either through image processing (like you said) or a more optimal method would be to send the `count` from the server.

Then instead of trying to make the **Image editable**. You can programmatically create that many EditTexts.

Comment: great but this image is very simple so i can follow your approach but there can be complex images too containing some icons logos in them which i can't make programmatically....

Comment: @sak you can make anything programmatically. It's just that the complexity of the code is going to increase significantly. I would suggest you keep track of the types of layout you might receive.